# Wrong number text that resulted in Maybe?

Tags: ios, messages

I got a text from a wrong number saying "This is Adam...off tomorrow". Why did my phone say Maybe: Adam?

Answer (score 1):

iOS can detect when someone you don't have in your contacts says "My name is..." or "This is..." and will automatically show that name in the contact information as "Maybe [name]"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/247699)

Comment: @IconDaemon how does this not answer the question? I said exactly why it's showing that.